# Microsoft Z3: Convert expressions to specific variables

Tags: z3, solver, smt

I'm using Microsoft's Z3 for some simple analyses of dynamic observations.  As part of this, it would be helpful if I could transform some formulae from using one set of variables into another target set of variables.

I'm really new to Z3, but I know it has some internal simplification rules and other means of transforming formulas...  Basically, I'm wondering if it's possible to do some transformations like:

```
(declare-const local Real)
(declare-const x Real)
(declare-const y Real)
(declare-const midstep Real)
(declare-const local_1 Real)
(declare-const foo_ret Real)

(assert (= local (/ x y)))
(assert (= midstep local))
(assert (= local_1 (+ midstep 1.0)))

(assert (= foo_ret local_1) :name toTransform)

; this is what I'd love to do - give Z3 a formula and a target set of variables
(special-simplify (= foo_ret local_1) (foo_ret x y))
; and have Z3 do the appropriate substitutions, etc to spit back 
; a "simplified" version in terms of foo_ret, x, and y, e.g.: 
;    (= foo_ret (+ (/ x y) 1.0))
```

I recognize that this isn't really the main goal of Z3, but I knew it had some capability for simplification / solving already... Judging from the help text, I got the impression that there are ways to design goals states and tactics for reaching them, but I couldn't really find information on how to do that based on Z3's `(help)` command (unless I'm missing something...).

I'm not really looking to do anything complex - just simple substitution / elimination of symbols not in the target set... I wonder if there's some way I can coax the tool into doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Z3 4.0 has support for tactics. They can be used to preprocess formulas and apply several transformations. The tutorial http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/guide contains more information about this new feature. The command `(help-tactic)` will display all tactics available in Z3.

That being said, none of the existing tactics do exactly what you want. I think the closest is the quantifier elimination tactic/command. In your example, we can use the quantifier elimination procedure to eliminate `local`, `local_1` and `midsep`. Of course, this procedure may be very expensive, and it is doing much more than just substituting variables. Here is an example. I'm using the command `elim-quantifiers` instead of the tactic `qe`.
Moreover, as you can observe, the result is not necessarily in a format we would call "simplified". The only guarantee we provided by the quantifier elimination procedure is:
if it succeeds, then the resultant formula is equivalent to the input formula.
We can use Z3 to prove that the result produced by `elim-quantifiers` is indeed equivalent to the formula `(= foo_ret (+ (/ x y) 1.0)))`.

http://rise4fun.com/Z3/jzZF

```
(declare-const x Real)
(declare-const y Real)
(declare-const foo_ret Real)

(set-option :pp-max-depth 100)

(elim-quantifiers 
  (exists ((local Real) (midstep Real) (local_1 Real))
    (and (= local (/ x y))
         (= midstep local)
         (= local_1 (+ midstep 1.0))
         (= foo_ret local_1))))
```